# Format numbers in comma separated value

Tags: javascript

I am using javascript to format the number with commas , it was working very fine.

But now the problem is if a value is comming in negative for example : **-792004**

It is returning the output like : **-,792,004** that is comma is in the start.

How can I modify this method ?

Here is my code :

```
function Comma(number) {
    number = '' + number;
    if (number.length > 3) {
        var mod = number.length % 3;
        var output = (mod > 0 ? (number.substring(0, mod)) : '');
        for (i = 0; i < Math.floor(number.length / 3); i++) {
            if ((mod == 0) && (i == 0))
                output += number.substring(mod + 3 * i, mod + 3 * i + 3);
            else
                output += ',' + number.substring(mod + 3 * i, mod + 3 * i + 3);
        }
        return (output);
    } else return number;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way I know which will helps you is [`toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) method on number:

```js
var x = 10033001;
var y = -10033001;

console.log(x.toLocaleString(), y.toLocaleString());
```

But for correction of your code, you can remove number sign with `Math.abs` and add it after with `Math.sign`.

```
var sign = Math.sign(number);
number = Math.abs(number);
// Do the conversion
return (sign < 0) ? ("-" + output) : output;
```

Comment: @AlinaAnjum You can use that *instead* of your method.

Comment: No i can't , because its a very old project and that method is called many more times

Comment: @AlinaAnjum `function Comma(number) { return number.toLocaleString(); }`

Comment: I can not use any built in method because this project is very old and there is a browser issue

Comment: but it's pretty nice solution . Up vote for your answer

Comment: but in internet explorer its showing trailing .00 i.e. -353,291.00 how can i resolve this

Comment: @AlinaAnjum You can split result by `.` then return first part: `return output.split('.')[0]`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
const comma = function(number) {
  const prefix = number < 0 ? '-' : ''
  number = String(Math.abs(number))
  if (number.length > 3) {
    const mod = number.length % 3
    let output = (mod > 0 ? (number.substring(0,mod)) : '')
    for (let i = 0; i < Math.floor(number.length / 3); i++) {
      if (mod === 0 && i === 0)
        output += number.substring(mod+ 3 * i, mod + 3 * i + 3)
      else
        output+= ',' + number.substring(mod + 3 * i, mod + 3 * i + 3);
    }
    return prefix + output
  } else {
    return prefix + number
  }
}
```

If the number is negative, it assigns `-` to `prefix`. Then it changes number to its absolute value (`Math.abs(number)`). In the end it returns value with `prefix`.

Comment: I've tried the answer before the edit . and it worked fine for me . can you elaborate what did you changed now ?